# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Hi a Laravel beginner here, I have a a manual select query which retrieve the data correctly via DB::select.

Now I want to paginate the result, however manual pagination doesn't work

```
$pagination = Paginator::make($book, count($book), 5);
```

and returning the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()
```

I am using Laravel 4.2

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Paginator` class. You should change your import to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;
```

Or remove the use statement completely since there's an alias registered for just `Paginator`

Comment: Thank you Sir, you nailed it
What are the differences between the two Paginators ?

Comment: The Facade proxies static calls of to an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Factory` which then creates an `Paginator` object. So the one you tried to use is the actual class and the Facade is a class that gives you easy access to the factory.

Comment: The Paginator Facade has been removed since laravel 5.* see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49964230/403999