# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Here is my code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
.
.
$collection = new Collection($guarantee_ticket);
// Paginate
$perPage = 3;
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1; // url.com/test?page=2
$pagedData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$pagination= Paginator::make($pagedData, count($collection), $perPage);
```

It throws:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()

And when I replace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;` with `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`, then it throws:

> Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator' not found

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manual Pagination Error - Laravel 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919497/manual-pagination-error-laravel-5-0)

Comment: use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;  $pagination= new LengthAwarePaginator(($pagedData, count($collection), $perPage); //I got the same error when doing migration from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 6):

Class [`Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php) doesn't have a `make()` method.

You instantiate it with the constructor. Also, 2nd parameter is `perPage`, 3rd is `currentPage`:

```
$pagination = new Paginator($pagedData, $perPage);
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/Factory.html) is definitely confusing, if not plainly wrong. It shows the Factory, but the view source links to `Laravel 4.2` class, that is nonexistant in `Laravel 5.6`.

Answer (score 3):

Today I have got similar issue after upgrading my project from `Laravel 7` to `Laravel 8` and updating it online on server.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::useBootstrap()
```

I have updated complete **vendors** folder online that have resolved my issue.

Earlier for pagination in Laravel 8; I have updated below code in my ProductsController.php file :-

Below Paginator class added at top of ProductsController

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Call useBootstrap function from Paginator class to use in any of the function where we are using pagination.

```
public function listing(Request $request){
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

Hope it will help someone in future!